# Jazz fusion groups, albums or songs with highly syncopated and accentuated drums and bass sections?

Tags: jazz, similar-artists, drums

I was wondering if someone could recommend a preferably modern fusion (or any other as long as it leans on the jazz side of things) group, album or track, that has specifically heavy,rich and syncopated drums and bass sections. I come across great complicated rhythm sections a lot when finding music, but they are scattered and I usually don't remember where I heard them, the last time I heard something resembling what I seek for is on the beginning of Otay from Dennis Chamber's Outbreak album.

Answer (score 2):

What a great question of an underrated genre.

What most people do not realize is many BIG names are actually categorized in what is known as **Progressive Jazz, Progressive Rock, Progressive Rock and Jazz, Rock and Jazz**.

Such bands are **Genesis, Steely Dan, Manfreds Mann's Band, Yes, Pink Floyd** and many others from the 60s-80s.

You did not mention if you like lyrics so here are just a few with and without lyrics.

- **Omar Hakim - Constructive Criticism**: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPWHlqygQqM
- **CAB - Cab**: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ennAB2TCCU (at 1:00 mark it picks up)
- **Kuru/Speak Like a Child - Jaco Pastorius**: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u3dKJATAJmA&list=PLm73ou9GEDEEEalDuj9Ct_fVe5Qcfu9EI
- **Autumn - Oceanworld**: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dp76oXaT6rI&index=8&list=PLm73ou9GEDEEEalDuj9Ct_fVe5Qcfu9EI

**Japanese artists are also very big into the Progressive Jazz Fusion**

- **Kazumi Watanabe**: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCt3GkLubZHbbgBfLriogNJQ

**Off topic:** I really like a Japanese Ska band that has Jazz infused music as well.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55XfGNP_gew&list=PLpK09eCUmot-PYY_cN7hiDkjq_XIv-koX

Comment: "Such bands are Genesis, Steely Dan, Manfreds Mann's Band, Yes, Pink Floyd and many others from the 60s-80s." - None of these are categorized as Jazz, at most their music shows a modicum of jazz influence.

Answer (score 2):

Some Return To Forever stuff has a similar sound, but there you have Lenny White and Stanley Clarke so you're gonna get this kind of groove.

Brand X, which sometimes featured Phil Collins on drums, had a little of this vibe as well.

Check out a song called [The Nag by John Scofield](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqlrSQ8BU84) (who happened to have Chambers in his band at the time).

Comment: Yeah Dennis Chambers!! Nice song... is this an impro or does it have a name?

Comment: The one linked is called "The Nag".